# Interpreting block of assembly accurately

Tags: assembly, x86

I have some questions about this block of assembly in IA32, which is a language I am teaching myself. Here, $eax should be taken to mean the integer 2. I have added these comments myself.

```
80499d0:       8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax // moves the count of these into the e a x register
80499d3:       83 e8 37                sub    $0x37,%eax // subtract 37 from 2, which would give you -35
80499d6:       83 f8 13                cmp    $0x13,%eax // then compare 13 to -35
80499d9:       77 6f                   ja     8049a4a <transform+0x80> // ??
80499db:       8b 04 85 a0 ae 04 08    mov    0x804aea0(,%eax,4),%eax // (0 + EAX (2) * 4) + 0x804ae0, so that's 0x0804ae0 + 8 ??
80499e2:       ff e0                   jmp    *%eax // jump to the address that the e a x registry is pointing to ??
80499e4:       e8 69 f9 ff ff          call   8049352 <call-function> // call this function
80499e9:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax // move the constant 0 into eax
```

So I have three questions about this:

1. What does "ja" do? In my reference sheet, it says that it "jumps above". So does that unconditionally just take you up?
2. Would the address generated by the "mov" be 0x0804ae8? My reasoning is in the comments.
3. What does it mean to "jump" to the pointer of eax? This is a register, so I'm not sure what's happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening there is a dispatch through a jump table. 0x804aea0 is the base address of the jump table. At 0x804aea0 there is a pointer to some executable code. At 0x804aea0+4 there's another pointer to some executable code. At 0x804aea0+8 there's another pointer to some executable code.

The %eax value is used to look up an entry in the jump table. If %eax was 2 after the sub instead of before the sub, the pointer at 0x804aea0+8 would be loaded into %eax and then the jump would go to whatever address was stored there.

The sub, cmp, and ja are used to verify that the initial value of %eax is within the acceptable range to not overflow the jump table. The jump table lookup will not happen if `%eax-0x37 > 0x13` and that's an unsigned comparison (for signed it would be jg not ja) which means the jump table is used for values of 8(%ebp) ranging from 0x37 to 0x4a. When 8(%ebp) is 2, the ja jump is taken, because -0x35 interpreted as unsigned is 0xffffffcb, which is much bigger than 0x13.

This technique is commonly used to implement a C `switch` statement with several close-together `case` values. This could be a switch statement in which the lowest `case` is 0x37 and the highest `case` is 0x4a. The value at 0x804aea0 points to the code that implements `case 0x37`; the value at 0x804aea0+4 points to the code that implements `case 0x38`, and so on. 0x8049a4a would be the `default` case, and you might also find it duplicated in the jump table in the slots corresponding to any numbers between 0x37 and 0x4a that don't appear as `case` labels.

0x80499e4 will very likely be one of the entries in the jump table, corresponding to either 0x37 or whichever was the first `case` in the source code.

Comment: Thank you, this is an excellent explanation. So for eax to not jump, it would have to be between int 55 and 74?

Answer (score 1):

> In my reference sheet, it says that it "jumps above".

Your reference sheet should be [Intel's Software Developer manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html?iid=tech_vt_tech+64-32_manuals).

1. That's "jump **if** above", i.e. jump if unsigned greater than (which also can be described as `CF=0 and ZF=0`).
2. Sounds about right if `eax==2`.
3. In this case it means that the instruction pointer will be set to the value of `eax`. For example, if `eax` contains the value 0x0804ae8, the instruction pointer will be set to 0x0804ae8 (so execution will continue at address 0x0804ae8).
   If you had wanted one more level of indirection (i.e. "jump to the address located at the address that `eax` points to") you would've written `jmp dword [eax]` in Intel syntax, and the machine code would have been `ff 20` instead of `ff e0`.

Comment: Can you clarify what it means for the instruction pointer to be set to the value? What impact does that have on the program?

Answer (score 0):

1. It is a conditional jump which will be affected by the previos CMP instruction. CMP sets some flags and JA will jump if 0x13 is above eax. http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/x86-jumps.html
2. Based on Michales comment below, it is the same as mov eax,[eax*4 + 0x804aea0], and then you are correct.
3. It means that the jump goes to the memory address that has the value that eax contains.

Comment: 1. Doesn't have to be a `cmp`. It can be any instruction that affects the flags (although, in this case it's a `cmp`). 2. It's the same as `mov eax,[eax*4 + 0x804aea0]` in intel syntax.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. I believe mov is used without b, w and l when it is unambigious how much is being moved